# В чем тут ошибка? AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Rock = open('Name.txt', 'r').replace('\n',' ')
```

Ошибка:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`open('file_name', 'r')` это не переменная типа string. Это объект, с помощью которого можно считать из файла уже в переменную.
Есть функция `read`, которая как раз считывает из файла.

Можно сделать вот так:

```
file = open('Name.txt', 'r')
Rock = file.read().replace('\n', ' ')
```

Или ещё короче:

```
Rock = open('Name.txt', 'r').read().replace('\n', ' ')
```

Answer (score 5):

Вы пытаетесь изменить файл `Name.txt` а он является типом `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>`, а  [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) используется только для изменения типа `<class 'str'>` для этого надо вывести текст в отдельную переменную как пример

```
rock = open('Name.txt', 'r')
r = rock.read().replace('\n', ' ')
print(r)
```

---

Или  так

```
rock = open('Name.txt', 'r').read().replace('\n', ' ')
print(rock)
```